# Expanding the elements DOM list in Chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

So when writing JavaScript one can use `debugger` in their code to fire a break point and pause the application at that point in, say, Chrome. This is all fine and dandy, but is there a way I can tell Chrome to expand the element DOM tree on refresh?

So, for example, instead of just seeing: [image: non expanded element DOM tree]

It would expand to show something along the lines of: [image: expanded element DOM tree]

Comment: I believe this isn't possible without some extension...

Comment: So any tips on how an extension could do this?

Comment: Exposing some function/object in the page context which can use a selector to expand elements (that's my idea, there may be better ways of doing this)

Comment: If the DOM tree is not modified on refresh, DevTools should restore the focused node after refresh